# System.Net.Mail.MailAddress does not allow Gmail GROUP contact

Tags: c#, gmail, sendmail, system.net.mail

I am using a Gmail business account, say `noreply@mycompany.com` to send a daily email reports to a few of my clients whose email addresses are from different domains. I use C# to send my email to Gmail's SMTP server.

```
var receiver = new MailAddress("receiver@domain1.com");
var receiver = new MailAddress("receiver@domain2.com");
var receiver = new MailAddress("receiver@domain3.com");
```

After a while I found out I had to modify code every time a new customer demands email report. So I want to make a group and maintain that group. Gmail has a Add Group settings in your account's "Contacts" page so I used that to create a group named ReportGroup and added those people. And in the code, this lines throws exception:

```
var receiver = new MailAddress("ReportGroup");
```

saying `The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.`

Well apparently this isn't a legit email address. Is there a way I can bypass this format check? Or is it doesn't make sense to do so?

In further attempts, I tried to name my group as `reportgroup@mycompany.com`. This time the email got sent without complain however the gmail server rejects the receiver, claiming that

```
50-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
550 5.1.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596 ai2si23882633pad.98 - gsmtp
```

So this isn't the way to go either. Could any one suggest a solution for me to allow someone non-programmer to maintain an receiver list to which my code sends report to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an [alias](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2727156?hl=en) for your group, and then send email to that address. Then you can continue to maintain the group as you normally do.

Comment: Hi Scott, please note that my clients are in different domains, not under `mycompany.com`. I can't add them as a group. The only such group I can manage is to create a User-created group for that `noreply@mycompany.com` user. So I can't create an alias for them.

Comment: In that case you're going to have to send multiple emails, one for each user. You could use Google's API to retrieve the list of email addresses in your group and then send messages to them individually. That way a non-developer can still maintain the groups.